# Error running flutter doctor -v on Mac M1 2020

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am facing an issue with Flutter on my Mac M1 2020. When I run flutter doctor -v, I encounter the following error:

```
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      _DefaultPub._runWithStdioInherited (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:447:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _DefaultPub.get (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:323:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      PubDependencies.update (package:flutter_tools/src/flutter_cache.dart:126:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      Cache.updateAll (package:flutter_tools/src/cache.dart:677:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1518:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1336:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:296:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:244:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:91:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I have tried reinstalling Flutter using the latest version.
I verified that Xcode and Android Studio are correctly installed and updated.
I checked my environment variables and added the Flutter bin directory to my PATH.
I ran flutter doctor --android-licenses to ensure I have accepted the Android licenses.
I have restarted my laptop multiple times.
I have cleaned the Flutter cache and re-run the doctor command.
I have tried running flutter doctor but it returns nothing.

However all of this has not been effective.
(Sorry if this post was formatted incorrectly, new to stack overflow)

Answer (score 0):

The error your are having might be due to the wrong sdk for flutter.
As you are using Mac M1, can you make sure that you have installed flutter sdk for the Apple Silicon from here https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos

[image]